# How to handle diagnostic logs from different resources of azure having different table log structure?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to send diagnostics logs of different azure resources of a specific subscription to Log Analytics Workspace(LAW)via EventHub.

But since we have different azure resource logs, each resource might have a different diagnostic log schema.

Then how can we handle this type of logs in Log Analytic Workspace(LAW) as all the logs stores in the form of tables in LAW ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a diagnostic setting is created for any resource within azure, tables are created based on the collection the resource is using:

- **Azure diagnostics:** All data is written to the AzureDiagnostics table. Because multiple resource types send data to the same table, its schema is the superset of the schemas of all the different data types being collected. For more information, on how each of the resource logs are collected, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-logs) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/azurediagnostics) document.
- **Resource-specific:** Data is written to individual tables for each category of the resource. For common and service specific schemas, refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-logs-schema).

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said, you could send events directly from the Resource to the Log Analytics Workspace using Diagnostic Settings.
The cost in this scenario is based on Gigabyte/dollars' of ingested logs into the LAW.

If you intend to use Event Hubs, which is basically a queue service, where events will be held usually only for 24 hours, you need a consumer to send those events into the LAW. Here are multiple options, you could do it via a Logic App to read that data, modify it and send it to the LAW. Price will be higher, as usually these resources cost by number of events.